# Dynamic dependent select option using AJAX and Laravel 5.8

Tags: ajax, laravel, dynamic, html-select

I am actually trying to obtain a dynamic dependent select option for city based on region and in my controller i am returning a string(using echo) but unfortunately the string is not rendering in the select option(of cities) on the browser. but i can see it by inspection or by printing on the console.

**my jquery:**

```
    <script >
    $(document).ready(function(){

     $('.dynamic').change(function(){
      if($(this).val() != '')
      {
       var select = $(this).attr("id");
       var value = $(this).val();
       var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
       var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
       $.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('dynamicdependent.fetch') }}",
        method:"POST",
        data:{select:select, value:value, _token:_token, dependent:dependent},
        success:function(result)
        {
         $('#cityName').html(result);
         console.log(result);

             console.log(result);
        }

       })
      }
     });

     $('#RegionName').change(function(){
      $('#cityName').val('');
     });

    });
    </script>
```

**: my controller**

```
class DynamicDependent extends Controller
{

    public function fetch(Request $request)
    {   
      $select = $request->get('select');
      $value = $request->get('value');
      $dependent = $request->get('dependent');

      $data = city::where($select,$value)->get();

     $output = '<option value="">Select '.ucfirst($dependent).'</option>';
     foreach($data as $row)
     {
      $output .= '<option value="'.$row->$dependent.'">'.$row->$dependent.'</option>';
     }
     echo $output;
    }
}
```

**:no eroor message**

**Here is the picture of the actual outpout :**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the response might not be that well formed.

Try to return a proper response instead of echoing yourself.

```
// other code in the controller ...

return response()->json($output);
```

If it doesn't help, please include the actual response you get in the browser/console.

Comment: thanks. actually i was using bootstrap select library and there is a class called selectpicker when i removed this class from the select tag of city it worked fine

Comment: Ah, I see. The thing with such custom selects is that they take the data from the real select element when created but do not watch it for changes. In those cases you can either destroy and recreate the custom selectpicker or there might be a dedicated method to sync the selectpicker with changes.

Answer (score 0):

thanks. actually i was using bootstrap select library and there is a class called selectpicker when i removed this class from the select tag of city it worked fine

Comment: If it's this plugin, here's a method that you are supposed to use when you change options: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh